# VBA Excel Inserting AutoSum on Dynamically Created Table

Tags: excel, vba

Im connecting to a database to populate an excel table with data. I am currently able to connect, execute a sql query, iterate over the results and format it as a table with no issue. I have a column I want to apply an `AutoSum` to, so like when you make a table in excel and Format as Table, you can select the last cell under the table, and click Formula -> Auto Sum. This gives you a sum, and it adjusts along with the table depending on which columns you want to filter on

[image]

How can I add this same type of an auto sum to my vba excel table via code?

```
'Other DB connection and SQL query code

Dim row As Double
row = 1

Do Until rs.EOF
    'Doing inserts from database
    Sheet4.Cells(row, 1).Value = rs.Fields("colname").Value
Loop

'Set it to be a table
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheet4.Range(Sheet4.Range("A1"), Sheet4.Range("I" & row))
Sheet4.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = "TTable"
```

Comment: Use the macro recorder and you get something like `Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(109,[Col3])"`  If the formula will be outside the table then you need to use `=SUBTOTAL(109,TTable[Col3])` as your formula.

Comment: Thanks, my lack of knowledge when it comes to excel functions makes things like this difficult sometimes. I was able to just set the value as a function `Sheet4.Cells(row + 1, 3).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(109,TTable[Col3])"`. This `SUBTOTAL` function was what I needed